# Differences between linear functions, multi-linear functions and morphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, morphism

I'm trying to understand some fundamental concepts of abstract algebra and, since i'm not a mathematician but a math enthusiast, i'm having some difficulties establishing connections.

A morphism should be a function among two algebric structures preserving the operations defined in them. A linear function should be pretty much the same, considering structures where, usually, operations aren't different. 
And here comes the doubt. A multilinear function generalizes the linearity concept, applying it "variable-wise" to multivariable functions. Is there, accordingly, any kind of generalization of a morphism? Is there any unifying concept able to embrace both as particular cases?

I'm asking since a multivariable function can also be treated linearly, considering the n-tuple of variables as a single element and, thus, applying the linearity concept to it.

I trying to figure which piece of the puzzle i'm missing.

Comment: What context are you considering a morphism in? If you're considering a morphism from category theory, then it may depend on the category you're working in. For example, a multilinear function in the category of vector spaces and linear maps can be viewed as a linear function from the tensor product of spaces. Similarly, if tensor products exist in other categories, they provide a better way of understanding the corresponding multi-input morphisms. Looking at the universal property of tensor products, products and coproducts might be enlightening.

Comment: I took a look at category theory and have understood some basic concepts but i was trying to establish that matter outside category theory. For instance, i knew that a multilinear function could be "made" linear through tensor product but as far as i could understand this does not generalize the concept of morphism nor brings it back to something general but simply provides an additional condition to be met (the new vector space must be generated by the cartesian product of the starting ones and must also satisfy the universal property).